# Vba word object height problems

Tags: excel, vba, object, ms-word

I have a pretty weird problem I don't understand.

I have a table with a bunch of information concerning how to work with a construction project. There is an increasing amount of 'recipes' that explains specific things about the project.
In the table each row is a recipe, and the columns are the how's, why's, when, notes etc.
My program takes the information of each row and puts it in a new sheet. Then it prints it as a pdf and takes the next row.
The problem is regarding the 'how' column. It can be quite long, so I use a word object to put it into the new sheet. It works great concerning rich text etc, but with particularly long texts, the height of the word object doesn't show the whole text. It seems the height of the object cannot exceed 1240px?
Any help?

Ps: using excel 2003, unfortunately.

```
Sub Embed_WordDocument_To_sheet()

Dim oWS As Worksheet ' Worksheet Object

Dim oWD As Document ' Word Document Object (Use Microsoft Word Reference)

Set wsFactark = Worksheets("Oversigtsark") ' thats the main table with the recipes

Set oWS = ActiveSheet

' embed Word Document
ws.Range("C3").Select
Set oOLEWd = oWS.OLEObjects.Add("Word.Document")



oOLEWd.Name = "EmbeddedWordDoc"
oOLEWd.Width = 375
'oOLEWd.Height = 10 ' will be changed later
oOLEWd.Top = ws.Range("C3").Top + 2 ' +2 for ikke at overstrege border-linjen
oOLEWd.Left = ws.Range("C3").Left + 5 ' samme
oOLEWd.ShapeRange.LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
oOLEWd.Placement = xlFreeFloating

' Assign the OLE Object to Word Object
Set oWD = oOLEWd.Object
wsFactark.Cells(I + 4, 13).Copy

oWD.Paragraphs(oWD.Paragraphs.Count).Range.PasteAndFormat (wdFormatOriginalFormatting)

With oWD.PageSetup
.TopMargin = 0
.BottomMargin = 0
.LeftMargin = 0
.RightMargin = 0
    .PageHeight = 1584 'max
    .PageWidth = 1584
End With


oOLEWd.Activate
oOLEWd.ShapeRange.ScaleHeight 1, msoTrue
oOLEWd.ShapeRange.ScaleWidth 1, msoTrue
oOLEWd.ShapeRange.Line.Visible = msoFalse

' trying to make the object show all the text, and not stop at 1240px. Doesn't work so far. :/ thought windowState would do it, but no. 
' prøver at få objectet til at kunne vise hele teksten, og ikke stoppe ved 1240 px.
oOLEWd.Application.WindowState = xlMaximized
oOLEWd.Height = Application.UsableHeight


oOLEWd.Width = 375
```

Comment: Why not wrap text so that you can fit it into a cell?

Comment: could you translate your comments to english? that would be very helpful (:

Comment: @PermaNoob because it is more than can be in a single cell.. The cell can show up to 1024 chars (i think) but store up to 32k chars. 
Using wraptext only gives me a bit of the text. 
I would like to be able to copy as much text as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't had a chance to test this, but it should parse your "recipe" into multiple cells, starting at C3. I'm assuming that these are written as sentences, so I'm finding the last period within 1024 characters, and putting everything up to that in the first cell, then continuing from there.

```
Sub StackTest()
Dim strRecipe As String
Dim intEndOfSent As Integer
Dim strPieceOfRecipe As String
Dim intCellRowToPasteIn As Integer

intCellRowToPasteIn = 3

If Len(strRecipe) > 1024 Then
    Do While Len(strRecipe) > 1024
        strPieceOfRecipe = Left(strRecipe, 1024)
        intEndOfSent = InStrRev(strPieceOfRecipe, ".")
        ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("C" & intCellRowToPasteIn).Value = Left(strRecipe, intEndOfSent)
        strRecipe = Right(strRecipe, Len(strRecipe) - intEndOfSent)
        intCellRowToPasteIn = intCellRowToPasteIn + 1
    Loop
Else
    ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("C3").Value = strRecipe
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: I wen't in that direction instead of using a word object but got stuck i think. Perhaps I should go back to it, if the word object height problem can't be fixed.

Comment: After an annoying morning, I decided to go back to this idea instead of using the word object. 
Thanks for your help!

Comment: By the way, i find that the RTF formats are gone when you enter the text into a string. Just a sidenote.